# Files don't import in vscode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, settings

I just started using vscode and my files in the same directory wont import to  files in the same directory. For example when I link to css or javascript files from an html file, they aren't read and the websits opens without the functions in the javascript file operating and same goes for the css file. When I imported flask forms from a file to my main flask application page in python, it wouldn't work and I would get the error, 'no module named 'flaskform'.

What settings configurations am I missing for vscode?

Comment: An example would be great for the readers. Please share the code.

Comment: I'm having similar issues on Mac these days. I work with JS files and for module imports to work, I have to keep the imported file open or the suggestion doesn't show the module name. :-|

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the debugger make sure it uses the correct working directory.
To use the current folder as the debugger working directory you can create a config file like described [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations).
In this file you can add `"cwd": "${fileDirname}"`
This works for Python debugging:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
    }
]
```